# Placing PHP array values into a javascript array?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, arrays

Is these a way i can loop through a PHP array and have the data outputted into a JavaScript array?

For example, the JS script below will not work

```
var mon_Loop = <?php echo $rowCount_Mon ?>;
var mon_Events = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < mon_Loop; i++)
{ 
   mon_Events[i] = <?php $divMon[i] ?>
}
```

I Know its because the "i" is not a php variable so therefore invalid inside the php section, but its just an way to show what i would like to achieve. The $rowCount variable count the number of rows and is then used to for the loop. Lets say, for example that I want to place the contents of the PHP array "$divMon[0]" into the javascript array  mon_Events[0].

I know that i can do it manually, like below

```
mon_Events[0] = <?php echo $divMon[0] ?>
```

But i have lots of these and therefore need the loop, Is there some JS or PHP that could do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it seems that your array `$divMon` contains numeric indexes, you can simply serialize it using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($divMon) ?>;
//...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped to no end.
Much Appreciated!

Comment: Plus use the `JSON_HEX_TAG` argument if you are inside a `<script>` block, to prevent any `</script>` sequences from prematurely ending the script.